# How to create Android Custome progress bar like Sine wave?

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I am new to android. I want to create a custom progress bar like sine wave. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It may save your day, take a look at

https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android

http://androidplot.com/

http://www.android-graphview.org/

These are simple graph where you can extract the "Sine View". You just need to make an interface callback to update the progress.